# Geolocalization with google maps and swift

Tags: swift3

I have a problem, i want to get in a variable the values of localization of the property mylocation of the api  google maps for ios in the languaje swift

Comment: or what i need implements for to get my coordinates of my location??

Comment: i have to use a methoc cLLocation of the system but i can`t save the coordinates on vriables of type global for use these

Answer (score 0):

if you wants this only use the property mapview.camera.target contents latitud, longitut
or mapview.camera.target.latitude or longitude
 Or you can use the protocol  that take a change of position

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let lastLocation = locations.last {
        driverLocation = lastLocation.coordinate
        updateCameraPosition(driverLocation)}}
```